# Escaping the control keyword in Terraform 0.11.x template data source

Tags: terraform, infrastructure

I am using Terraform version 0.11.14. I have a template_file data source that I'm using to render a config file.

Within the file, I have this line:

```
match => { "message" => "%{HTTPD24_ERRORLOG}" }
```

The documentation says to escape

```
${HTTPD}
```

then I would use:

```
$${HTTPD}
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to work out how to escape this control keyword though, I continue to get the error: 
`Invalid template control keyword; "HTTPD24_ERRORLOG" is not a valid template control keyword.`

I have tried using double %, eg. %%{HTTPD}. No luck.

Unfortunately upgrading to 0.12.x is not currently an option.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of the template provider are you using?

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR for your response; you were on the right track. I resolved this yesterday by pinning the template provider to 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by pinning the template provider to version 1.0. Not ideal, but if sticking on Terraform 0.11, certainly fixes the issue.